# How do I link up the contact form?

Tags: html, css

I'm being a bit cheap here and stealing a website template for my business rather than making one from scratch.

However my question is on the contact form - how do I link it up to email it to my email?

```
<div id="contact_form">
            <h4>Send us a message now!</h4>
            <form method="post" name="contact" id="ok" action="#">

                <label for="author">Name:</label> <input type="text" id="author" name="author" class="required input_field" />
                <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>
                <label for="email">Email:</label> <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="validate-email required input_field" />
                <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>

                <label for="phone">Phone:</label> <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="input_field" />
                <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>

                <label for="text">Message:</label> <textarea id="text" name="text" rows="0" cols="0" class="required"></textarea>
                <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>

                <input type="submit" class="submit_btn float_l" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send" />
                <input type="reset" class="submit_btn float_r" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

that's my form - also I need to add white to the background of the actual form (its all black ) so you can't see the boxes - how do I go about doing that?

cheers for the help

Comment: It requires more than just a form. You need a backend that handles the posted data. [Tutorial](http://www.learnphp-tutorial.com/SendingEmailwithPHP.cfm#.UM5sSG-5O68)

Comment: You cant just use HTML and CSS without anything else. You need something like PHP or ASP or any other backend language that can work the information stored within your form.

Comment: @bobthyasian incorrect, you can use a `mailto` action.

Comment: @Petah `mailto` opens up a default mail service. Like Outlook.

Comment: @bobthyasian, no, the `mailto` action is client side. Try it.

Comment: And it wasn't technically his question.

Comment: Hey guys , cheers for the help - however I'd rather it be built into the webpage - not loading up outlook or anything like that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The most basic way is to set the `action` to your email address:

```
<form action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
```

http://webdesign.about.com/od/forms/a/aa072699mailto.htm

Comment: Thanks - however I'd rather it all be built into the webpage (not loading up the users email)

Comment: @chuck you get what you pay for.

Comment: @Petah You're getting paid?!

Comment: `mailto:` URIs as form actions are [highly unreliable](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html). They are not suitable for use on the WWW.